# MVC Posting back umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, umbraco, backend, umbraco7

What is the best approach to have a kind of edit form for the site visiter with umbraco?

A very simple example is an application (Website) that has 2 pages.

### First page: a list of countries.

So in umbraco i created a document type with template called "List"
there is a Surface controller that gets called when the page is visited. That controller gets a list of countries (lets say from a list of objects)

```
public class Country 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Country(string name)
    {
        Id = new Guid(); //Or something likewise... whatever
        Name = name;
    }
}

List<Country> countries = new List<Country>();
countries.add(new Country("UK"));
countries.add(new Country("US"));
countries.add(new Country("France"));
countries.add(new Country("Belgium"));
```

The surface controllers gets this object back and renders a list of these countries in its razor view, next to each country there is a button called "Change this country"

Back in Umbraco, i also have a second document type with template called "Edit"
This should be used for some Editing mechanics of that Country...

I would also prefer to have a routing like this

```
http(s)://localhost:12345/Edit/2354
```

instead of

```
http(s)://localhost:12345/Edit?id=2354
```

What is the best thing to do that?
I have tried it with surface controllers, but i can't post back
I have tried with Route Hijacking and completely hijacked the MVC route.

I have also searched many hours on the internet. but i cant find a good solution for this very simple problem.
at least in my opinion this problem is very simple :) but i just can't get my head around it.

I hope someone is around that can solve this.

Comment: I disagree with the other poster that you don't need a surface controller in this case, but please post your controller code first and edit your model because I'm not sure what's your model exactly or what's the response you get.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't need to use a Surface controller for this, simply use the standard MVC structure, create a standard Controller, and your corresponding View and Model. Use a HttpGet ActionResult to return your page and then create a new update ActionResult to update your items, by passing the Country Id. Please see this standard Microsoft documentation for some details. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but off course i need to preserve the content of the Umbraco document type. there are other things on that page as well.

Comment: I'd still do it normal way as this page won't be used by multiple content pages(as far as I see) and in case you would like to use the standard ASP.NET MVC approach, then you can simply get your Umbraco content data as IPublishedContent and populate your view model, and then use it on your view and do your CRUD operations standard way. Here is a code sample to do this: var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
IPublishedContent content = umbracoHelper.TypedContent(123);

Comment: Another way could be using PetaPoco, please see my blog about this or see the alternative url, hope it helps. http://nurhak-kaya.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-use-petapoco-tiny-orm-ish-thing.html https://creativewebspecialist.co.uk/2013/07/16/umbraco-petapoco-to-store-blog-comments/

Answer (score 0):

And did a bit of more research for you, here is a good example which explains this nicely, this might also help you to sort out your problem if you don't want to go for my first option. https://codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-to-create-a-contact-form-in-umbraco-using-mvc-and-c/

Comment: I did look at those examples. it's a very good blog the codeshare.co.uk but it still lacks what i am looking for. I am getting there in a different way, if i have everything sorted out, i will post an example as an answer later on.